# Царство Денвера

Tags: denwer

Доброго времени суток :) Такая вот **Ситуация**:

Давным давно, в тридевятом царстве был у меня **модем** и стоял **XAMPP**. Прошли эти страшные и хмурые дни и я купил себе **роутер**,а также поставил **Денвер**. И тут у меня возник **ВОПРОС:** *Каким образом дать доступ к денвер своим гражданам тридевятого царства* . Знаю, что нужно открыть *80-порт* на роутере и еще там пошаманить, искал много в царстве **Гугла**, но ничего не нашел. Может ли кто-то мне поэтапно рассказать как воплотить эту темную магию в жизнь? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Вырвиглазный вопрос.

Comment: О_о Вот это да) Автор явно пишет проекты ночью, а днем не спит :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выбросьте ваш денвер, к чертям собачьим, и поставьте нормальную связку LAMP/LNMP. Это раз. Во-вторых, да, откройте в роутере 80-й порт и установите адрес для сервера (компьютера на котором крутятся ваши сайты) в этом самом роутере. В-третьих, если вы достаточно нуб в таких вопросах, тогда либо почитайте соответствующую литературу, либо набивайте себе шишек от незванных гостей на ваш сервачок.

Comment: Понял, благодарю) Да, еще нуб, я б сказал рак, спасибо за совет :)

Comment: Рак и нуб - это две разные сущности.

Comment: Установить всё своими ручками - это хорошая практика, тем более, что информации о том, как это делается, в [инете просто море](http://bit.ly/YzbJEt)

Comment: @istem, суть одна)

Comment: @Deonis, да, конечно, ща почитаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Удивительное дело, но автор проекта Денвер у себя в списке [частозадаваемых вопросов](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/), добавил три, и, о чудо, один из них как раз об [этом](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html)!

Comment: Читал я там :) Вот и не получилось, думал мне тут кто-то расскажет)

Comment: Забыть о Денвере, т.к. проект "умер". Если уж и пользоваться сборками такого плана, то [Open Server](http://open-server.ru/)

Comment: угу, понял, ща почитаю, узнаю, что к чему. Спасибо.